# pdb: "var = value" did not create the var in current function?

Tags: python, pdb

See following example:

```
$ cat -n foo.py
     1  def func():
     2      v = another_func()
     3      print v
     4
     5  func()
$ pdb foo.py
> /root/tmp/foo.py(1)<module>()
-> def func():
(Pdb) break 2
Breakpoint 1 at /root/tmp/foo.py:2
(Pdb) cont
> /root/tmp/foo.py(2)func()
-> v = another_func()
(Pdb) v = 123            <-- manually create the var
(Pdb) jump 3             <-- skip another_func()
> /root/tmp/foo.py(3)func()
-> print v
(Pdb) next
UnboundLocalError: "local variable 'v' referenced before assignment"
> /root/tmp/foo.py(3)func()
-> print v
(Pdb)
```

Where is the var `v` if it's not created in the `func()`?

Comment: Man, the pdb docs really don't make this clear.

Comment: [Looks like this might be a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue22577), but it doesn't look like anyone cared enough to reply to the bug report or do anything about it.

Comment: This is the first time for me to try `jump` to skip some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [pdb bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue22577), where changes to local variables are lost after a jump. It was reported years ago, but it never got fixed.